# Здраствуйте моя проблема заключается что я не могу сделать систему ставок в игре на VkAPI

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Перепробовал уже все но не как не получается сделать так чтоб если пользователь вводил ставку цифрами выводилось "Ставка Принята!"
а если присутствовали другие символы "Ставка НЕ Принята!" и чтобы эта система не реагировала на кнопку отмена

```
    n1 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"] 
    if msg == "монетка" or msg == "отмена":
        otmena = VkKeyboard(one_time=True)
        otmena.add_button("Отмена")
        send_some_msg(id, "Введите сумму ставки!", otmena)          
        for event in longpoll.listen():                 
            if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
                if event.to_me and event.text:
                    msg = event.text.lower()
                    for i in msg:
                        if i == n1:                     
                            simvol_alp = True
                        if i != n1:
                            simvol_alp = False
                    if simvol_alp == True:
                        send_some_msg(id, "Ставка Принята!")
                        msg = monstavka
                    else:
                        send_some_msg(id, "Ставка НЕ Принята!")
```

Comment: Цикл `for i in msg` работать не будет, т.к. Вы сравниваете символ со списком + сообщение, скорее всего, будет состоять из одной цифры. Лучше замените его на `simvol_alp = msg in n1`, ну и ещё не забудьте про `monstavka`, а то она взялась из ниоткуда :)

Comment: Здраствуйте спасибо большое за помощь но мо;ете еще подсказать вот я заменил                                  simvol_alp = msg in n1                                                  
if simvol_alp == msg in n1:              
    send_some_msg(id, "Ставка Принята!")                      else:                                              
    send_some_msg(id, "Ставка НЕ Принята!")      но опять всегда выводит "Ставка НЕ Принята!"

Comment: Зачем в условии писать сравнение того, что мы только что сделали в предыдущей строке? Ещё я сделал ответ для выхода из комментариев

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дублирую из комментария к вопросу:

```py
for i in msg:
    if i == n1:                     
        simvol_alp = True
    if i != n1:
        simvol_alp = False
```

Незачем изучать каждый символ строки, когда можно проверить именно САМУ строку на предмет нахождения в списке. Для этого цикл можно аккуратно заменить на `simvol_alp = msg in n1` — она как раз поместит в `simvol_alp` нахождение ставки в списке допустимых значений.

```
n1 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"] 
if msg == "монетка" or msg == "отмена":
    otmena = VkKeyboard(one_time=True)
    otmena.add_button("Отмена")
    send_some_msg(id, "Введите сумму ставки!", otmena)          
    for event in longpoll.listen():                 
        if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
            if event.to_me and event.text:
                msg = event.text.lower()
                simvol_alp = msg in n1
                if simvol_alp == True:
                    send_some_msg(id, "Ставка Принята!")
                else:
                    send_some_msg(id, "Ставка НЕ Принята!")
```